# Getting the control of a context menu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, contextmenu

I have a context menu that looks like this

```
 A
 |--1
 |--2
 |--3
```

I need to access the object that the context menu is called from, after selecting 1 2 or 3

meaning if this is a context menu of a textbox1 then I need to access that object, how do I do that?

Forgot to mention, this is a WPF application. so Im using the System.Windows.Controls
and the ContextMenu is created programmatically

Comment: A context menu doesn't require having a owner control.  Especially not for a TextBox, it implements its own context menu.  But if you use the right way to invoke it then SourceControl is an excellent way to find the source control back.  Be sure to use the Show() method that takes a Control.

Comment: found the answer from a similar question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884117/get-owner-of-context-menu-in-code

viky's code works, but I had to cast it twice. (I guess looping it is possible for better flexibility)

Answer (score 11):

You can walk up the tree and get the control from the [`ContextMenu.PlacementTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget.aspx), e.g.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as MenuItem;
    while (item.Parent is MenuItem)
    {
        item = (MenuItem)item.Parent;
    }
    var menu = item.Parent as ContextMenu;
    if (menu != null)
    {
        var droidsYouAreLookingFor = menu.PlacementTarget as TextBox;
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the simplest and best solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the [SourceControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol.aspx) property of the ContextMenuStrip that owns the context menu item that was clicked.

For example, in the Click handler for the menu item:

```
private void aToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = ((sender as ToolStripMenuItem).Owner as ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl;
       ...
}
```

Of course if you only have one ContextMenuStrip on the form, you can just reference it directly

```
var control = myContextMenuStrip.SourceControl;
```

Comment: I used MenuItem and a ContextMenu class.
is there a difference between using a ContextMenuStrips and just a ContextMenu and MenuItems (the context menu is generated dynamically) besides the SourceControl property?

Answer (score 1):

Slight tweak to HB's answer.  HB deserves the credit.  Helped me find a DataGrid.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;
    ContextMenu cm = (ContextMenu)item.Parent; 
    Popup popup = (Popup)cm.Parent; 

    var finalGoal = popup.PlacementTarget as DataGrid; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the

```
ContextMenu.SourceControl
```

that's the variable that calls the context menu. all you need to do is cast the control

Answer (score 0):

found the answer from a similar question

[Get owner of context menu in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884117/get-owner-of-context-menu-in-code)
viky's code works, but I had to cast it twice.

I guess looping the casting of the Parent is possible for better flexibility 
(more casts depends on how deep the clicked item is)

Answer (score 0):

**Ugly Solution**

I am searching for a better way to do the same thing. For now, the code below works:

```
TextBlock tb = ((sender as MenuItem).Parent as ContextMenu).PlacementTarget as TextBlock;
```

Replace `TextBlock` with your control's type.